# Can the Forbiddance spell be placed on a moving area? (like a ship)

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The spell [Forbiddance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/forbiddance.htm) reads:

> Forbiddance seals an area against all planar travel into or within it.

Can this area be mobile? Such as a the deck of a ship?

More specifically, my campaign is in Eberron, can this be used on an airship?

Comment: Although yours *is* more specific, I think it's generally pretty close to the question [Do spell effects move if the object they are cast on moves?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63913/8610) (which, incidentally, *also* mentions airships).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes, that seems to be the basis of this question. Should I close this as a duplicate? Even though the other question has no answer?

Comment: I only hesitated in case there was something specific to the spell *forbiddance* that made it different from the other possibilities mentioned in the other question's answers; as that doesn't appear to be the case, closing it as a duplicate's probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no RAW answer**

The rules do not address this case (casting an location-based spell on a movable location). You would have to venture outside RAW to find an answer.

Comment: So, that is to say that there is no mention in the RAW anywhere about whether spells are fixed or relative in their position?

Comment: That is correct - though you may want to specify the scope of RAW you want, as I'm sure some third party naval supplement somewhere addresses it.  These is a Pathfinder AP player's guide that does, for example...

Comment: I will accept this because it is pretty much is the only answer I will get with RAW. Thanks.