# Would the Magnificent Mansion if cast on a moving object remain where it was cast or stay with the object?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

The question has arisen in my mind on whether when a mage has cast a [Magnificent Mansion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magnificent-mansion) (5e) while on an object that is in motion (boat, airship, giant alpaca, etc), would the doorway to the Mansion then remain static in place?

The relavent wording from the spell:

> You conjure an extradimensional dwelling in range that lasts for the duration.  **You choose where the entrance is located**. The entrance is 5 feet wide and 10 feet tall [...]

I could see that this would indicate that the mage has chosen the location to be the giant alpaca and as such that is where the door would remain located.  Or that the mage has chosen the place in space that the door is located and as such the door would remain there despite the alpaca continuing to move forward.  Or perhaps something else might occur...?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I agree they are similar but the wording of the Hut is more specific to the parameters of the Hut in place and wording like immobile and stationary while the Mansion only specifies the doorway opposite the desire of the caster to place it in space. I think the ambiguity makes it an adjacent but not identical question

Comment: Related: "[Is Leomund's Tiny Hut stationary relative to the ground or to the surface it's cast on?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102339)" "[Does a persistent spell effect cast on a moving platform move with the platform, or is it fixed in space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134302)" "[What is the relative return point of a creature banished by the Banishment spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161613)" "[Constant Movement and round based combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107220)" "[How does the Blink spell work on moving vehicles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148614)"

Comment: Also related: "[Can a permanent Teleportation Circle be made on a moving vehicle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103173)" and "[What happens when an Immovable Rod is activated while in a vehicle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69917)" and "[Can the Silence spell be cast on a character or object that can then be moved?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170048)" and "[Can static illusions be cast on moving objects so the illusion moves with them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104290)" and "[Would a moving ship break glyphs of warding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112699)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your DM decides

D&D is not a physics simulation. D&D is a game that makes simplifying assumptions to support gameplay. In practical terms, this normally means that  immovable effects are immovable relative to the frame of reference of the game action. Often, if you use a battlemap, they do not move around on that battlemap.

For example, if you are moving around on a flying carpet the zips across overhead, then the entrance could be stationary relative to the the overall area, not the carpet. If you are all on a sailing ship drawn on the map, and a sea monster attacks, the entrance  could be stationary relative to the ship. Or your DM could rule it will be stationary to the ocean, and the ship will sail on, leaving you stranded in the mansion.

As the **rules do not really explicitly speak on this, it will be up to your DM** to adjudicate what the frame of reference is (a conclusion also supported by the many [linked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102339/is-leomunds-tiny-hut-stationary-relative-to-the-ground-or-to-the-surface-its-c) [related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112699/would-a-moving-ship-break-glyphs-of-warding) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/does-a-persistent-spell-effect-cast-on-a-moving-platform-move-with-the-platform)).

Comment: Appreciate the answer.  So many questions ultimately fall into this category I suppose but that is the primary job of a DM!  Adjudicate and maximize the fun.

Answer (score 3):

### Everything is moving

Unless you choose the one *extremely specific* frame of reference where it isn’t.

The planet revolves and orbits the star. The star orbits the galaxy. The galaxy moves in rather complicated ways with respect to the local cluster and so on.

Or, maybe your world is more fantastical and takes place on a disc with a central volcano that spews new land while old land around the edges breaks off an floats away? And civilizations have to migrate to the Centre or collapse. Hang on ... I have to write this stuff down for my next campaign.

Anyhoo, this spell is way less problematic than the ones that create immobile stuff without telling you *what* they are immobile with respect to. Here the rules say you “choose” where to put it. For mine, that means you can choose the frame of reference.

Comment: "Everything is moving" is certainly a modern Physics interpretation, sure.  It is not obvious that any particular game world operates under these rules, however.  If I'm  riding a giant eagle toward something, my arrows fired at it don't do more damage than if I am flying away.  A magic spell's definition of what is "moving" doesn't have to correspond to the RW any more than a transformation spell has to obey conservation of mass.

Comment: @Krit AFAIK both Forgotten Realms and Eberron are also moving but not via the same mechanism that planets move in our universe.

Comment: @Kirt your arrows don’t do damage because of momentum or energy or any physical concept - they do damage because the rules say they do.

Comment: @DaleM I think that is my point - the rules are not making an attempt to model RW physics principles.