# Does "a point you choose" include any movable surface?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, targeting

I read somewhere that spells like *Darkness* and *Silence*, where the effect of the spell spreads from a point I choose within range, can be cast on the surface of a moveable item. But after extensive googling, I couldn't find confirmation on it anymore. These are the relevant parts of the spell descriptions:

> **Darkness**
> Magical darkness spreads from a *point you choose within range* to fill a 15-foot radius sphere for the duration. ...

> **Silence**
> For the duration, no sound can be created within or pass through a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on *a point you choose within range*. ...

So theoretically, does this mean that a Warlock with the Devil's Sight incantation can cast *Darkness* on their armor and "carry" it around with him? Giving him semi-permanent (Concentration) advantage to targets without Devil's Sight/Truesight?

Another example would be someone casting *Silence* on an enemy mage, rendering them unable to cast spells with Verbal components also semi-permanently (Concentration)?

Comment: Related: "[Is Leomund's Tiny Hut stationary relative to the ground or to the surface it's cast on?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102339)" and "[Does a persistent spell effect cast on a moving platform move with the platform, or is it fixed in space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134302)" and "[What happens when an Immovable Rod is activated while in a vehicle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69917)" and "[Can static illusions be cast on moving objects so the illusion moves with them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104290)"

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate to some of this): "[Can the Silence spell be cast on a character or object that can then be moved?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170048)"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the next paragraph of Darkness:

> If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it. Completely covering the source of the darkness with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.

So you can cast Darkness on your armour, if you take your armour off. Otherwise it has to be an item you are holding. Your sword would work.

Silence does not have this wording, and so silence doesn't move with an object you cast it on.

Comment: This is a pretty common trick for melee-locks--the most common tactic I've seen is for a Warlock to cast Darkness on something like a small rock, so they can just stuff it in a pouch or small bag when they want to shut off the spell temporarily. I've even seen DMs allow them to tie a string to the rock--hold it while casting the spell, then tie it to the Warlock's belt so their hands are free, but can still drop the rock into their pouch when they want the dark-bubble to go away without dropping the spell..

Comment: I think casting darkness on your own worn gear is meant to be permissible - nothing stops you grabbing (and holding) your own armour while you cast the spell, even if you are *also* wearing it. The next statement is an "OR" clause that prevents you from interfering with another person's possessions, not your own.